# How to externally style with CSS the specific 3 td tags on the html table generated by the pager row of a asp.net gridview control

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview, css-selectors

The working version of the html table generated markup with css is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/nexU/JkUCQ/1/

As you can see all I need is to set these align and width styles for those 3 specific TD tags on a external css and override the ones that are automatically generated by asp control.

Thanks in advance for your help.

/*
I want 1st pagerRow TD to have width 10%
I want 2nd pagerRow TD to have width 80%
I want 3rd pagerRow TD to have width 10%

*/

/------------style.css------------/

```
.pagerRow
{
    background: #3D6AA2;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    height: 30px;
}

.pagerRow td
{
    border: solid 1px red;
}
```

/*------------ part of html generated by control------------*/

```
<table id="mainContacts" class="contactsBase" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="header_row">
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
        </tr>
        <tr class="pagerRow" align="center">
            <td colspan="5">
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" width="25%"> <!--How to set these align and width styles on external css and override these ones that are automatically generated by asp control?-->
                            </td>
                            <td align="center" width="50%"> <!--How to set these align and width styles on external css and override these ones that are automatically generated by asp control?-->
                                <p> 1,2,3,4,5 </p>
                            </td>
                            <td align="right" width="25%"> <!--How to set these align and width styles on external css and override these ones that are automatically generated by asp control?-->
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Working fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/JkUCQ/4/

(updated based on your new input)

Add this to your CSS:

```
.pagerRow tr td:nth-child(1) {
    width:10% !important;
}
.pagerRow tr td:nth-child(2) {
    width:80% !important;
}
.pagerRow tr td:nth-child(3) {
    width:10% !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. your solution works on jsfiddle, but somehow it does not work on the aspx page. don't know why. rendered markup still applies widths: 25% 50% 25% but now page area does not look good after new styles: screenshoot of what I'm seeing after adding your styles is here: http://d.pr/i/Q0hJ

Comment: Your code applies inline styles. Use my updated answer to overcome that.

Comment: Thanks for your help and time. I tested your updated solution and it works on jsfiddle, but not on the aspx page, it still appears as the screenshoot I posted before, not sure why it does not work. http://d.pr/i/ZLX9

Comment: It did not work on the aspx page, but you made it work on jsfiddle. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to be of help to you. It seems that some debugging is left on your end to fit it on your actual aspx pages.